# The '-ing' form and clauses

Tags: grammar, subordinate-clauses, ielts

Which of these sounds more natural?

1. Rural areas are beneficial to people's health, because they provide people with opportunities to escape pressure and noises of modern life.
2. Rural areas, which provide people with opportunities to escape pressure and noises of modern life, are beneficial to people's health.
3. Rural areas are beneficial to people's health, providing people with opportunities to escape pressure and noises of modern life.

I am learning how to write IELTS essays and I read the third sentence from some online teaching materials written by a teacher. But somehow I feel that it's a little weird. Am I right? Or are there any ways to improve this sentence?

Comment: Hello, Xin Xu, and thanks for your interest in English Language & Usage. Unfortunately, the question "which of these [alternative wordings] sounds more natural?" is a request for primarily opinion-based feedback (at least in situations like this one, where all of the options pass muster on grammatical grounds), which is off topic at this site.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that. I thought sentence 3 was grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the first two are slightly more natural than the third. 
But, much more importantly,
the second one doesn't mean the same as the first and the third. 
The first one explicitly describes a causal link. 
#3 does the same, although perhaps less explicitly. 
But the second sentence just states two facts, without really connecting them. 
Consider:

> Vaccinations, which cause some brief discomfort,
>   can protect you against illness for a period of months or years.

Vaccinations don't protect you *because* the injection hurts. 
So, if you want to explain why rural areas are beneficial to people's health,
don't use #2.

P.S. Consider this variation on #3:

> Rural areas sustain people's health ***by*** providing them
>   with opportunities to escape the pressure and noises of modern life.